# Expression of Bianchi identity in associated bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, field-theory, gauge-theory

Theorem 5.14.2 of [Mathematical Gauge Theory by Hamilton](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-68439-0) states that the curvature form $F^A_M\in\Omega^2(M,Ad(P))$ satisfies the third form of the Bianchi identity $d_AF^A_M=0$ where $F^A_M$ is the form in $\Omega^2(M,AD(P))$ given by the correspondence between horizontal $k$-forms of type Ad on $P$ with values in $\mathfrak{g}$ and forms on $M$ with values in $Ad(P)$. The proof of this is basically applying this isomorphism to the bianchi identity $dF^A+[A,F^A]=0$. I am interested in how to show that $d_AF^A_M\in\Omega^2(M,AD(P))$ actually corresponds to $dF^A+[A,F^A]$. It has to do with the fact that with respect to a local gauge $s:U\rightarrow P$ we can write $(d_A\omega)_s=d\omega_s+A_s\wedge \omega_s$ and the fact that for $1$-forms the wedge product "is the commutator".
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this question, it is useful to look how the exterior covariant derivative $\mathrm{d}_{A}$ acts on form on $P$ and not on $M$. Let us fix the following data.

1. A smooth manifold $M$.
2. A principal $G$-bundle $P$ over $M$ with $\mathfrak{g}=\mathrm{Lie}(G)$.
3. A finite-dimensional representation $(V,\rho)$ of $G$ and let $E:=P\times_{\rho}V$ be the associated vector bundle.

Let $A\in\Omega^{1}(P,\mathfrak{g})$ be a connection $1$-form. Now, there are two common ways to define the object $\mathrm{d}_{A}$, i.e. the exterior covariant derivative induced by $A$. One approach is to first of all define a connection $\nabla^{A}$ on $E$ using a parallel transport. Then, one defines $\mathrm{d}_{A}$ to be the exterior covariant derivative induced by $\nabla^{A}$. This approach is for example followed in Hamilton's book *Mathematical Gauge Theory*. However, there is another approach, which can be found in many other books (e.g. Baum's *Eichfeldtheorie*), which is equivalent. In this approach, one first constructs a natural derivative on forms on $P$, which preserves horizontal forms, and then one induces $\mathrm{d}_{A}$ on forms on $M$ using the usual isomorphism. The connection $\nabla^{A}$ is then recovered as the operator $\mathrm{d}_{A}$ acting on zero-forms.

In more details: First of all, we would like to define a natural derivative on $\Omega^{k}(P,V)$. A natural canditate is to take the usual exterior derivative $\mathrm{d}:\Omega^{k}(P,V)\to\Omega^{k+1}(P,V)$. However, in the language of principal bundles, it is more natural to have an object preserving horizontal vector fields. Hence, we consider
\begin{align*}
        \mathrm{D}_{A}:\Omega^{k}(P,V)\to\Omega^{k+1}(P,V)
    \end{align*}
which we define for all $k\in\mathbb{N}_{0}$ and for all $\omega\in \Omega^{k}(P,V)$ by
\begin{align*}
    (\mathrm{D}_{A}\omega)_{p}(v_{1},\dots,v_{k}):=(\mathrm{d}\omega)_{p}(\mathrm{pr}_{H}(v_{1}),\dots,\mathrm{pr}_{H}(v_{k}))
\end{align*}
for all $p\in P$ and $v_{1},\dots,v_{k}\in T_{p}P$, where $\mathrm{pr}_{H}:TP\to H$ denotes the projection onto the Ehresmann connection $H$ defined by $A$. Now, it turns out that this operator has the following very nice property:

> $D_{A}$ maps $\Omega^{k}_{\mathrm{hor}}(P,V)^{\rho}$ to $\Omega^{k+1}_{\mathrm{hor}}(P,V)^{\rho}$. Furthermore, for $\omega\in\Omega^{k}_{\mathrm{hor}}(P,V)^{\rho}$, the following formula holds
> $$D_{A}\omega=\mathrm{d}\omega+A\wedge_{\rho}\omega,$$
> where $\wedge_{\rho}$ is the natural wedge product $\wedge_{\rho}:\Omega^{k}(P,\mathfrak{g})\times\Omega^{l}(P,V)\to\Omega^{k+l}(P,V)$ defined by the pairing $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{\rho}:\mathfrak{g}\times V\to V,(X,v)\mapsto \rho_{\ast}(X)v$, i.e. $A\wedge_{\rho}\omega:=\sum_{a,b}(A^{a}\wedge\omega^{b})\langle T_{a},e_{b}\rangle_{\rho}$ for basis $(T_{a})_{a}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ and a basis $(e_{a})_{a}$ of $V$.

Secondly, thanks to the natural isomorphism

$$\Omega^{k}_{\mathrm{hor}}(P,V)^{\rho}\cong\Omega^{k}(M,E)$$

the operator $D_{A}$ induces an operator $\mathrm{d}_{A}:\Omega^{k}(M,E)\to\Omega^{k+1}(M,E)$. This is the same operator as defined using the strategy of parallel transports used in Hamilton's book. Usually, people denote both $D_{A}$ and $\mathrm{d}_{A}$ by the same symbol, but I wanted to avoid confusions. In particular, you see that under the isomosphism above, you get the following correspondence:

$$D_{A}\omega=\mathrm{d}\omega+A\wedge_{\rho}\omega\quad \mapsto \quad\mathrm{d}_{A}\omega_{M}$$

where $\omega_{M}\in\Omega^{k}(M,E)$ is the form obtained from $\omega\in\Omega^{k}_{\mathrm{hor}}(P,V)^{\rho}$ via the isomorphism above. Now, if you take $(\rho,V)$ to be the adjoint representation $(\mathrm{Ad},\mathfrak{g})$ of $G$ (and hence $\mathrm{Ad}_{\ast}=\mathrm{ad}$), you get the formula

$$D_{A}\omega=\mathrm{d}\omega+[A,\omega]$$

which is a global version of the local formula you very mentioning. In particular, you see that $\mathrm{d}_{A}F_{M}^{A}$ really corresponds to $D_{A}F^{A}=\mathrm{d}F^{A}+[A,F^{A}]$ as you claimed.

Comment: Ok this really really helps, however I am still struggling to see why in the case of the adjoint representation we get the commutator. Following the definition if both $A$ and $\omega$ are written as $A^a\otimes T_a$ and $\omega^b\otimes \omega_b$ we get
$
A\wedge_{\rho}\omega:=\sum_{a,b}(A^{a}\wedge\omega^{b}) \rho_*(T_{a})T_{b}=\sum_{a,b}(A^{a}\wedge\omega^{b}) [T_{a},T_{b}]$
is this equal to $[A,\omega]$?

Comment: Moreover in this approach we have actually \emph{defined} $d_A$ as the composition of $D_A$ with the isomorphism right?

Comment: Yes it is. The notation $[\cdot,\cdot]:\Omega^{k}(M,\mathfrak{g})\times\Omega^{l}(M,\mathfrak{g})\to\Omega^{k+l}(M,\mathfrak{g})$ is the natural wedge product induced by the Lie bracket $[\cdot,\cdot]:\mathfrak{g}\times\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{g}$. By definition, $[\alpha,\beta]=\sum_{a,b}(\alpha^{a}\wedge\beta^{b})[T_{a},T_{b}]$ where $\alpha=\sum_{a}\alpha^{a}T_{a}$ for $\alpha^{a}\in\Omega^{k}(M)$ and similar for $\beta$. (I usually prefer the notation $[\cdot\wedge\cdot]$ to stress that it is a mix of wedge product and Lie bracket.)

Comment: @PunkZebra yes exactly, it is the composition with the isomorphism, or better, the conjugation, i.e. $\mathrm{d}_{A}=I^{-1}\circ D_{A}\vert_{\Omega^{\bullet}_{\mathrm{hor}}(P,V)^{\rho}}\circ I$ where $I:\Omega^{k}(M,E)\to\Omega^{k}_{\mathrm{hor}}(P,V)^{\rho}$ denotes the isomorphism.

Comment: I cannot stress how much you've helped me, thank you (after thoroughly reviewing everything I'll accept your answer)

Comment: @PunkZebra your welcome :-)